# If $P\times{\bf2}$ order-embeds in $Q\times{\bf2}$, does the poset $P$ embed in the poset $Q$?

Tags: posets

A function $f:P\to Q$ from a poset $(P,\le_P)$ to a poset $(Q,\le_Q)$ is an *order-embedding* if, for all $p,p'\in P$, $p\le_P p'$ if and only if $f(p)\le_Q f(p')$.

We partially order the Cartesian product $P\times Q$ of posets $(P,\le_P)$ and $(Q,\le_Q)$ as follows: for $(p,q),(p',q')\in P\times Q$, $(p,q)\le_{P\times Q}(p',q')$ if $p\le_P p'$ and $q\le_Q q'$.

A *chain* is a poset $(C,\le)$ that is totally ordered: that is, for all $c,c'\in C$, either $c\le c'$ or $c'\le c$.  For $n\in\mathbb N$, we denote the $n$-element chain by $\bf n$; its elements are $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$.

Consider the poset $S_3:=({\bf 2}\times{\bf 2}\times{\bf 2})\setminus\text{{(0,0,0),(1,1,1)}}$.

The poset $S_3\times{\bf 2}$ is shown in the figure below. The colors of the lines are merely for ease of reading.

[image]

If you put lines between the "corresponding" elements of the two parts of the diagram below, you will have $(S_3\times{\bf 2})\times{\bf 2}$.

[image]

Let $P$ and $Q$ be finite non-empty posets.
If $P\times{\bf2}$ order-embeds in $Q\times{\bf2}$, does $P$ order-embed in $Q$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The two-element anti-chain $\{0,0'\}$ does not embed into ${\bf 4} = \{0,1,2,3\}$, but $\{0,0'\} \times {\bf 2}$ embeds into ${\bf 4} \times {\bf 2}$ using the embedding
\begin{align*}
(0,0) &\mapsto (0,1)\\
(0',0) &\mapsto (2,0)\\
(0,1) &\mapsto (1,1)\\
(0',1) &\mapsto (3,0).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you!  On page 300 of Professor Garrett Birkhoff's 1942 article, "Generalized Arithmetic," he writes, "It suggests the conjectures that if $AX$ and $AY$ are finite, then
$AX\subset AY$ may imply $X\subset Y$," where it appears (page 284) that he uses "$\subset$" to denote an order-embedding. See also Question 4 at the top of the second column of page 192 of "Was Gelfand Right? The Many
Loves of Lattice Theory, " Notices of the American Mathematical Society $\bf 69$ (February 2022): https://www.ams.org/notices/202202/rnoti-p190.pdf#page=3

Comment: Frankly I would not be surprised if this question had already been negatively answered somewhere in the literature.  The above counterexample is not exactly difficult to find.  (The very first thing I tried was the case when $P$ was a chain (where the claim is true), and the second thing was the case when $P$ was an antichain, leading quickly to the above example.)